# scapy::traceroute setting source ip address

Tags: python, scapy, traceroute

I have a setup in which my source server is connected to a network using an anycast address, as a result I need to use source ip every time I ping or traceroute any destination in the network I am connected to.

I am currently experimenting with scapy and using sr methods but traceroute in scapy has some powerful features that I need to use. The traceroute in scapy does not take any source addresss as the sr methods do.

Is there a way around this? Or are there any wrappers on top of scapy::traceroute that allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting [*Scapy*'s `traceroute` function's code](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/src/cd8f482c8858e940959bf9c6c03a8d336db0edaf/scapy/layers/inet.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#inet.py-1295) reveals that it's pretty straightforward while most of its powerful features lie with the `TracerouteResult` class it instantiates with the result received from a simple `sr` invocation, as can be seen by the current implementation:

```
@conf.commands.register
def traceroute(target, dport=80, minttl=1, maxttl=30, sport=RandShort(), l4 = None, filter=None, timeout=2, verbose=None, **kargs):
    """Instant TCP traceroute
traceroute(target, [maxttl=30,] [dport=80,] [sport=80,] [verbose=conf.verb]) -> None
"""
    if verbose is None:
        verbose = conf.verb
    if filter is None:
        # we only consider ICMP error packets and TCP packets with at
        # least the ACK flag set *and* either the SYN or the RST flag
        # set
        filter="(icmp and (icmp[0]=3 or icmp[0]=4 or icmp[0]=5 or icmp[0]=11 or icmp[0]=12)) or (tcp and (tcp[13] & 0x16 > 0x10))"
    if l4 is None:
        a,b = sr(IP(dst=target, id=RandShort(), ttl=(minttl,maxttl))/TCP(seq=RandInt(),sport=sport, dport=dport),
                 timeout=timeout, filter=filter, verbose=verbose, **kargs)
    else:
        # this should always work
        filter="ip"
        a,b = sr(IP(dst=target, id=RandShort(), ttl=(minttl,maxttl))/l4,
                 timeout=timeout, filter=filter, verbose=verbose, **kargs)

    a = TracerouteResult(a.res)
    if verbose:
        a.show()
    return a,b
```

Therefore, you may invoke `sr` in a similar manner to that performed here, but with a source address as well, and pass on the result to the `TracerouteResult` class in order to make use of its powerful features.

**NOTE:** an equivalent approach can be applied to [*Scapy*'s `traceroute6` function's code for *IPv6*](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/src/cd8f482c8858e940959bf9c6c03a8d336db0edaf/scapy/layers/inet6.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#cl-2908).

Comment: @Yeol thanks,  I don't know why it did not occur to me that I could just look up the code.